# let's give him a big round of applause. (what's the round?)

Tags: meaning-in-context

We hear a lot people say "Let's give sb a big round of applause."

'round' means around or every round like in a boxing match. It also means not rectangular nor square.

What's the meaning of 'round' in a phrase"a big round of applause"?

Comment: A [round³](https://www.lexico.com/definition/round) is a **session** or **sequence** of something, as in a round of drinks, a round of discussion etc.

Comment: It is like a round in a boxing match.

Answer (score 4):

In the idiomatic expression “a round of applause” the term *round* refers to a repeated number of hand clappings. The audience is invited to  clap their approval in "rounds" of applause.

Basically, "round" in this instance means “over and over”.

> **[round of applause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/round-of-applause)**
> a period of time during which people are clapping